# How to find in different kinds of files

Tags: command-line, find, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working on a Ubuntu Windows app on my Windows-10 PC, the result of `uname -a` is the following:

```
Linux DOMINIQUEDS 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #48-Microsoft Fri Apr 27 18:06:00 PST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'm doing some C++ development, and I'd like to know which source files (`*.cpp` or `*.h`) are including the file `Sample.h`, so I launched following command:

```
find ./ -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.h" -exec grep -i "include" {} /dev/null \; | grep "Sample.h"
```

This seems not to be working: only the `*.h` files, containing `include` and `Sample.h` on the same line, are given.

However I know for sure that the `-o` construction for finding different kinds of files is correct:

```
find ./ -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.h"
```

=> here I get a list of `*.cpp` and `*.h` files.

This leaves me with two possibilities:

- Either the behaviour is correct: the `-exec` parameter is only used on the last `find` result. In that case, can somebody tell me how I can perform the `-exec` on all `find` results?
- Either the behaviour is wrong. In that case, does somebody know if this is a general Ubuntu problem/Windows-10 Ubuntu app problem/... and if any solution can be expected and when?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I know for sure that the -o construction for finding different
>   kinds of files is correct:
>
> ```
> find ./ -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.h"
> ```

True, but the precedence of `-or` is not that high. From [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html):

```
   Please note that -a when specified implicitly (for example by two tests
   appearing  without an explicit operator between them) or explicitly has
   higher precedence than -o.  This means that find . -name afile -o -name
   bfile -print will never print afile.
```

So:

```
-name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.h" -exec grep ...
```

Is like:

```
-name "*.cpp" -or ( -name "*.h" -exec grep ... )
```

And not like:

```
( -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.h" ) -exec grep ...
```

You need:

```
find . \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.h' \) -exec grep -H '#include.*Sample\.h' {} +
```

(I assume you used `/dev/null` to make `grep` print the filename? The `-H` option does that.)

Comment: indeed, the `/dev/null` is an old trick for showing the filename.

Answer (score 2):

With modern `grep`, you don't need `find` at all e.g.

```
grep -r --include='*.cpp' --include='*.h' 'include' . | grep 'Sample\.h'
```

or - better (given that the order of the search terms is unambiguous)

```
grep -r --include='*.cpp' --include='*.h' 'include.*Sample\.h' .
```